# Is it possible to highlight custom words in PhpStorm?

Tags: php, phpstorm, syntax-highlighting

I was trying to find how to highlight certain words in PhpStorm but have found nothing.

The main idea is, I want to change background colour for any usage of DebugLogger class in order to improve its visibility in my code. It's an ordinary user-created PHP class which is used mainly in static manner, so I need to highlight exactly the "DebugLogger" word, not instances of the class.

I can apply custom colours for all class names but not for one or two I want to mark out. Is it possible at all?

Comment: It's not possible to associate custom color with specific search string of any kind (variable/function/class) that would work automatically in any file. For current file you may always invoke Find on page to see matches in current file.

Comment: There is a plugin -- "PHP Inspections (EA Extended)". It has one inspection -- "Probable bugs: forgotten debug statements" that highlights  any standard debug statements (like `var_dump`, `print_r` and alike). I may suggest [contact plugin author](https://bitbucket.org/kalessil/phpinspectionsea/issues?status=new&status=open) and ask to allow providing custom class/function/variable names that would be highlighted in addition to the standard ones. Then in PhpStorm you may create and then assign custom severity for this particular inspection so it can be highlighted using custom colors.

Comment: @LazyOne I've created an issue with my proposal. Thank you for the idea.

Comment: see feature request https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEABKL-5473